# Manipulating Data Using MigrationBuilder in Migration File Up/Down

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, database-migration

In my database, I have two tables; People and Alias. Originally, People contained a series of fields, including `FirstName`, `MiddleName`, and `LastName`. Alias also contains `FirstName`, `MiddleName`, and `LastName`, but rows are tied to a row in People, a unique person.

I've changed the model so that People no longer contains `FirstName`, `MiddleName`, and `LastName`, and added the field `IsPrimary` to Alias.

I've created a migration file which should reflect the new state of these tables. What I want to do now is add to the migration file code that will take every row in the People table, obtain the data in the `FirstName`, `MiddleName`, and `LastName` fields, create a new row in Alias, insert `FirstName`, `MiddleName`, and `LastName` into that new row, and set the `IsPrimary` field to true. This would be within the Up method. I need to do the reverse for the down function.

How can I perform these actions within the migration file?

Here's part of the migration file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace ACC.Data.Migrations
{
    public partial class Add_IsPrimary_To_Alias : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "People",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                    DOB = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: true),
                    EyeColor = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Facility = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    HairColor = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    HeightInches = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    Notes = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    PrimaryPhone = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Race = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Sex = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    WeightLbs = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_People", x => x.Id);
                    });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Aliases",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                    FirstName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    IsPrimary = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    LastName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    MiddleName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    PersonId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Aliases", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Aliases_People_PersonId",
                        column: x => x.PersonId,
                        principalTable: "People",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Aliases");
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "People");
        }
    }
}
```

After some more looking around I found some docs about [Data Motion and Custom SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#sql).

> There is no native support for data motion yet...

Does this mean what I am trying to achieve isn't possible?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show the current migration file ?

Comment: @Sampath I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  migrationBuilder.Sql for this purpose, where you can pass sql for aliases update etc.
You can't use any model or context because it can be incompatible with not updated database yet.